# Full text search in more than 2 tables with different data

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match-against

Hi I have this sql statement

```
SELECT *,  MATCH (first_name,last_name) AGAINST ('*?*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score, MATCH (groups.groupname) AGAINST ('*?*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS sscore
FROM users INNER JOIN groups  
WHERE MATCH (first_name,last_name) AGAINST ('*?*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH (groups.groupname) AGAINST ('*?*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
 ORDER BY 'score' Desc
```

1) How can I ORDER by the joint score? I mean with this sql statement, it creates a score for the first match and a score for the second. How can I add those two scores and order by that score?

2) Also I know since the data are not the same the INNER JOIN way is not the best. is there anyway I can remove it?

and lastly, if i remove IN BOOLEAN MODE when i use for example *sim* and the first_name is simos I don't get the result. In fact I get an empty result set while in boolean mode if I put *sim* I'll get the simos as result.

EDIT: I responded my 2nd question by doing this

```
(SELECT `id`,MATCH(first_name,last_name) AGAINST ('?*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM `users` WHERE MATCH(first_name,last_name) AGAINST ('?*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

union
(SELECT `groupid`, MATCH(groupname) AGAINST ('?*') AS score FROM `groups` WHERE  MATCH(groupname) AGAINST ('?*') )

This though changes everything though as I don't need a joint score but still have the problem with the IN BOOLEAN MODE

Answer (score 1):

`order by 'score'` is incorrect, it'll be trying to order by a fixed string `score`', not the alias you created in the `match ... against`.

Try

```
...
ORDER BY (score + sscore) DESC
```

Comment: Ok this is better than just order by score. Definitely better. Although I created a UNION query but this one still seems to work better. How do I remove the IN BOOLEAN MODE but still have the proper results? When I don't use in boolean mode, when I don't put the whole name, I don't get any results at all. LIKE works better than this :P

Comment: you'd need boolean mode to support the wildcards. Otherwise it'd be run in "natural language mode", which doesn't do the wildcards.

Comment: I can't really understand what you mean. In boolean mode, everything works perfect and the wildcard is supported. At least I see the results I want. For example I ahve a  5 letter word , if I put the first thre letters + * IN BOOLEAN MODE it will return the results but if I do that without boolean mode it won't return any results

Comment: Exactly. because in boolean mode, `*` is a wildcard. If you do it outside of boolean mode (which in mysql is "natural language" mode), then a `*` is a character like any other, so you're searching for text that literally has a `*` followed by your search text followed by another `*`.

Comment: And what can I do in such a situation? I mean can I do something different or return in boolean mode? Unfortunately in boolean mode the score is always 1 or 0 so it doesn't make sense to create a boolean mode full-text search instead of a where something=something*. Why did they have to do that :P I mean they created such a wonderful tool but only half of it is working :/